# Measuring "uniqueness of fit" or "unique goodness of fit" of a model to some data

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, inference, multiple-comparisons, goodness-of-fit

Given some parametric model, we can determine the best-fit parameters to some data set. Once we have quantified goodness of fit for each parameter set, we can easily generalize from this to measure the goodness of fit of the model in general. There are many standardized metrics and methods to do this, often as the best-case goodness of fit on the parameter space, perhaps weighted by the priors on the parameters.

However, sometimes we need to quantify not just the goodness of fit but something like the **"uniqueness of fit"**. That is, given a model, some data sets will yield only one parameterization which fits relatively well, whereas others will yield many parameterizations which all fit relatively well. We want to quantify how much "ambiguity" there is when choosing from the possible interpretations.

Also, sometimes we don't want to look at just the uniqueness, but something like the **"unique goodness of fit"**. For instance, the model may have only two parameter choices, which both have likelihood equal to 25% given some data set, whereas another one may have only two parameter choices which both have likelihood equal to 75% given the same set. Both are equally ambiguous when trying to choose a parameterization from the model, but the second performs better in general than the first, so we could incorporate that into our metric as well.

**Question:** are there some standardized methodologies to quantify this kind of thing, either what I'm calling **"uniqueness of fit"** or **"unique goodness of fit"** above? (It's ok if these involve priors on the parameter space.)

The uniqueness of fit seems like it could be measured with some kind of entropy on the model parameter space, treated as a random variable given the data set. You could probably generalize this to "unique goodness of fit" fairly straightforwardly, but I'm sure some standardized way to do this already exists.

Comment: in some sense the Fisher information does this? The steeper the likelihood is, the more certain we are in the optimum and the fewer parameter options that could fit. Multicollinearity in linear regression is an example of a flat likelihood with a lack of identifiability, which is the worst case for uniqueness. And if the Fisher information fits the bill then basically this means that model SEs are doing the trick

Comment: But how does that quantify how many optima there are? We want to differentiate between if there's only one clear global optimum with high likelihood, and several which also have high likelihood.

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean. Yeah, I’m not sure